# Use function result as columns in query with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1 and let's say I have a type in PostgreSQL like:

```
CREATE TYPE sticker AS (
    customer_id integer,
    customer_machine_id integer,
);
```

and I have a plpgsql named get_sticker that returns the type sticker...

I can do this fine:

```
select get_sticker(a_value), * from foo_bar;
```

But, this returns the result in a tuple (which totally makes sense).  But, how can I convert (basically unpack) to columns?

It seems like it would be something like the following, but it fails.

```
select get_sticker(a_value).*, * from foo_bar;  -- <<<< FAIL
```

Error message:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
SQL state: 42601
```

Comment: When something fails it's worth providing the error message.

Comment: @CraigRinger : Excellent point.  I will update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an extra set of parentheses:

```
select (get_sticker(a_value)).*, * from foo_bar;
```

Comment: Thanks!  So, simple, but I could not figure it out for the life of me (and could not figure out the right terms to google to find the answer)!